# Question regarding proof, concerning finite groups and definite hermitian forms.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a question regarding the proof of theorem 4.8 on p.336 in the following [paper](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Edrinfeld/Hypergeometric_motives/Beukers-Heckman.pdf). I try to give an short outline.

---

In the second part of the proof, the author wants to show, that the group $H$ is finite. Therefore he constructs a diagonal embedding
$$\phi : H \to \prod_{k \in (\mathbb{Z}/h\mathbb{Z})^*}H_k$$
and shows, that the image of $H$ is contained in $GL(mn,\mathbb{Z})$ and also leaves invariant a definite hermitian form on $\mathbb{C}^{mn}$. He then directly cocludes, that $H$ has to be finite, **what i dont understand**.

*What we have:*

Well, we have that $H$ is isomorphic to a subgroup $im(\phi) \subset GL(mn,\mathbb{Z})$ and a hermitian form $F$ on $\mathbb{C}^{mn}$ invariant under $H$. So up to isomorphism, we have

$$H \subset U_F(\mathbb{Z}) = \{X \in GL(mn,\mathbb{Z})\mid X^t F \overline{X}=F\}.$$

Also $F$ being definite means, that  $H \subset U(mn,\mathbb{Z})$. But what is the relation now, between definite hermitian forms an finite groups?

Comment: Try to write the condition of a unitary matrix with integer coefficients. You can only have $0$ and $\pm 1$ as coefficients.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Let $X \in H$. Since we consider integer coefficients to begin with, we have $X^t X=I_n$, making $X$ orthogonal. So $H \subset GL(mn,\mathbb{Z}) \cap O(mn,\mathbb{Z})$. Thus $X$ is a signed permutation matrix with entries $0,\pm1$.  But how does this help me? My guess is now, that i need an isomorphism from this subgroup of $GL(mn,\mathbb{Z})$ to a finite group now.

Comment: There are only finitely many such matrices $X$.